# 'Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined' Implementing Google Chart into my SAPUI5 project

Tags: javascript, charts, calendar, sapui5

I'm trying to implement the calendar chart from the google chart library https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar

However, when I try to implement it, I seem to get an error 'Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined'

After carefully debugging, I have found out that the library itself DOES load as I can use certain google code however, it is missing a file called 'library-preload.js' when calling the chart function.

'failed to load 'lib/googleChart/library-preload' (failed to load 'lib/googleChart/library-preload.js' from /webapp/lib/googleChart/library-preload.js:' I have tried multiple ways of implementing the library just in case this was the problem such as implementing the library via HTML and into the manifest.json file, however, I still get the same error.

Many thanks.

Attached as listed;

- code where the library is loaded.
- Init
- the function called to load the chart (line 3 is where i get the error - 'Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined')
- Screenshot of Library directory
- Screenshot of the error in debugger

  sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("lib.googleChart", "/webapp/lib/googleChart/");

  ```
      onInit: function () {

  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["calendar"]}); 
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawChart()); 

  },





     drawChart: function() {
        debugger;
     var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
     dataTable.addRows([
        [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
        [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
        [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
        [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
        [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
        // Many rows omitted for brevity.
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 4), 38177 ],
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 5), 38705 ],
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 12), 38210 ],
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 13), 38029 ],
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 19), 38823 ],
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 23), 38345 ],
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 24), 38436 ],
        [ new Date(2013, 9, 30), 38447 ]
      ]);
     var calender = this.getView().byId("calenderChart");
     //var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(calender);
     var options = {
       title: "Red Sox Attendance",
       height: 350,
     };

     chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  ```

  },

[Screenshot of Library directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68O7a.png)

[Screenshot of the error in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7UUF.png)

Comment: You cannot just copy the `library.js`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand by what you mean, can you elaborate?